# enable and disable firebase notification using switch buttons

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Enable and disable the firebase notification using switch buttons.? i used php code for backend to take the fcm token and place it in the database(phpmyadmin).Then i generate a push notification to the app. The notification coming correctly but i can't stop it. i want to enable and disable the notification with switch buttons.

```
public class FcmMsgService  extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID1 = "channel_id" ;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {

        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
        Intent intent = new Intent(click_action);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID1);
        builder.setContentTitle(title);
        builder.setContentText(message);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
        // super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    }
}
```

Mainactiviy

````
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Switch switchBtn;
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sendBtn= findViewById(R.id.send_token);
        prefEditor= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit();
        prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

        switchBtn= findViewById(R.id.switch2);

            switchBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                    if (switchBtn.isChecked()) 
                          {

          // when i user enable button the notification can allowed to come
                        prefEditor.putString("checked","yes");
                        prefEditor.apply();

                          }
                    else
                     {
         // when i user disable button the notification cannot allowed to come
                        //how to Stop the firebase notification?????
                        prefEditor.putString("checked","no");
                        prefEditor.apply();
                   }}
```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY5yp.png
````

Comment: Solution depends on scenario: do you send notification based on device token so to the particular user/s or sending is based on `FirebaseMessaging topic?`

Answer (score 1):

For enabling notification via a topic:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance()
            .subscribeToTopic(yourTopic);
```

Then for disabling:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic(yourTopic);
```

In your code:

```
if (switchBtn.isChecked()) {
  // Subscribe here
  FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(yourTopic);
  prefEditor.putString("checked","yes");
  prefEditor.apply();
}
else {
  // Subscribe here
  FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic(yourTopic);
  prefEditor.putString("checked","no");
  prefEditor.apply();
}
```

Also, as this function returns a task, you can do:

```
TopicManagementResponse response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic(
    registrationTokens, topic);
// See the TopicManagementResponse reference documentation
// for the contents of response.
System.out.println(response.getSuccessCount() + " tokens were unsubscribed successfully");
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you.

Comment: please see the php code image i the below mainactivity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try unsubscribe from each topic?

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("YourTopic");
```

Also, this code can be simplified:

```
switchBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                    prefEditor.putBoolean("checked", switchBtn.isChecked()).apply();
            }
}
```